# Why it is good to clean the SecurityContextHolder after completion of a webRequest?

Tags: java, spring-security

Why is it required to clean the requestContextHolder after completion of the request? I read spring documentation to find my answer but does not understood clearly.

Comment: What did you read exactly?

Comment: @Andres : it states "Clearing the ThreadLocal in which the context is stored is essential, as it might otherwise be possible for a thread to be replaced into the servlet container's thread pool, with the security context for a particular user still attached. This thread might then be used at a later stage, performing operations with the wrong credentials."

Comment: @sahil-gupta The explanation from your comment should be part of the question, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An HttpServletRequest is attended by a thread. Many Servlet containers don't create a new thread for each request they receive, but recycle threads in order to save resources. In case you store data on a ThreadLocal scoped variable, this variables would survive the process of a request and still be there when the thred is used again by another request.  That's why you have to clean them.